# Pure virtual function which must set variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

recently i have read some about pure virtual function concept in c++ and i wonder, given following code:

```
class First
{
public: 
    virtual void init() = 0;
protected: 
    bool initialized;
};

class Second : public First
{
public:
    void init() { ((*someting*) ? (initialized=true) : (initialized=false)); 
};
```

if creator of `First` class wanted to ensure the implementation of `init()` MUST set `initialized` variable either true or false how can they do that? Is there an option to enforce implementation of pure virtual function to set any variable inherited from base class?

Comment: _"Is there an option to enforce implementation of pure virtual function to set any variable inherited from base class?"_ No.

Comment: What you can do is to set the bool member to false (or true) when you declare it (in the base class)

Comment: Pity... Anyway, @πάνταῥεῖ - thanks for quick answer!

Comment: In C++ it is common for the derived class to throw an exception if its constructor fails. That way uninitialized objects will never exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can make `init` protected and have it return `bool`.
Then have a new `initialize` method which is public and also sets the `initialized` member.

Since `init` now has a return value, it must be set by anyone who implements derived classes.

```
class First
{
public: 
    void initialize() { initialized = init(); }

protected: 
    virtual bool init() = 0;
    bool initialized;
};

class Second : public First
{
public:
    bool init() { return (*something*); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check if `initialized` has been set or not, because it cannot represent the third state "undefined".

**Solution 1**

Protect the pure virtual function, make it return the initialized value and call it via a non-virtual wrapper

```
class First
{
public: 
    void init()
    {
        initialized = initImplementation();
        // check initialized here
    }
protected: 
    virtual bool initImplementation() = 0;
    bool initialized;
};
```

**Solution 2**

Change initialized to an enumeration with the states undefined, non-initialized, initialized, protect the pure virtual function and call it via a non-virtual wrapper, that then checks if the variable has been set:

```
class First
{
public: 
    void init()
    {
        initImplementation();
        // check initialized here
    }
protected: 
    virtual void initImplementation() = 0;
    enum
    {
        undefined,
        initialized,
        uninitialized
    } initialized;
};
```

**Solution 3**

Get rid of initialized, just throw an exception in `init()` if something goes wrong. The caller will then know that something went wrong.
As a sidenote, you can throw also from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while the direct answer to your question is *no*. There is some technique you can employ to get a guaranteed call of your `init` function.
Let's say you have the following base class:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void init() = 0;
private:
    bool initialized = false;
};

void Base::init() 
{
    std::cout << "Called from base!\n";
    initialized = true;
}
```

And the following derived:

```
class Derived: public Base
{
    friend class Enforcer<Derived>;
public:
    void init() override
    {
        std::cout << "Called from derived!\n";
    }
private:
    Derived()
    {
    }
private:
    using BaseClass = Base;
};
```

Look at the private constructor and the friend declaration: you can no more create this class without help of the `Enforcer` class(this step is not really required but it will really force any user of the `Derived` class to use `Enforcer`). And now we need to write the `Enforcer` class, here it is:

```
template<typename T>
class Enforcer: public T
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Enforcer(Args&&... arg): T(std::forward<Args>(arg)...)
    {

    }

    void init() override
    {
        T::init();
        T::BaseClass::init();
    }
};
```

The whole example on the [ideone](http://ideone.com/aaf9cj).

Yes it has its drawbacks(you need to add some additional stuff to the `Derived`  class) but it solves the requirement pretty neatly, in my opinion.